# Android - How to mark timestamps on a SeekBar

Tags: android, events, timestamp, drawing, seekbar

I will be working on an app that records button presses, where I can play back that session on a SeekBar.  Each event will be timestamped from the value of a Chronometer.  When playing back, on each of those recorded events I will play a sound.  That part shouldn't be a problem.

Now, what I would like to figure out is how I can mark the timestamps on the SeekBar by drawing red bars at the positions where each event occurred.  I would like the red bars to be drawn prior to playback.

Since I haven't started this app yet, I don't have any code at this time.

Comment: Well, does anyone have an idea?

Comment: I would look at [this library](https://github.com/karabaralex/android-comboseekbar), [this library](https://github.com/ademar111190/android-phased-seek-bar), and [this library](https://github.com/edmodo/range-bar). While none do exactly what you want, they should give you some ideas of how to augment the rendering of a `SeekBar`-style component.

Comment: what was your effort?code?researches? 

Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: He could use a <View> with a background color, width set to match_parent and a height of 2dp-5dp wrapped in an FrameLayout that me might be able to draw on top of? Adding as a comment because I don't want to do the work to confirm this. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were to this, I would use the following procedures:

1. Grab a handle to the seekbar view in my java code and save the width.
2. The width represents your timescale starting at 0 to whenever the user stops acting on the view. Lets call that stop value T (seconds).
3. After the recording completes, divide the width into seconds based on T.
4. Each time stamp will map to an x-coordinate based on #3. Draw a red vertical line centered over that seekbar view at x. If you draw it on top, it might mess up seekbar interaction.

I know this isn't code but hopefully it will give you a good idea on how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't mark anything on seek bar. So don't use seek bar. Just use a simple Pixels to draw as a line with width of match_parent and height of 2dp. Put a small circular image as seek bar over there. Then mark pixels wherever you want marking.

Look at the concept

...................O............................................................

This is your seekbar. Mark particular point for you dynamically.